# phpStorm, xDebug and Chrome debugging

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, wamp, phpstorm

I have reinstalled phpStorm 8 and Wamp 2.5
I set the appropriate php.ini file with the following.

```
zend_extension = "e:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11.dll"
;
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = true
xdebug.remote_port="9005"
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = On
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "e:/wamp/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
```

In phpStorm under Stettings->PHP->Debug

[image]

I then set a breakpoint and start the debug listener in the top right screen of phpStorm.

I have downloaded the `JetBrains IDE Support 2.0.8` extension for google chrome and set the port to 9005 as-well.

but phpStorm never stops on a breakpoint and I dont get the incoming convection messages that phpStorm normally gives when debugging?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: *"I have downloaded the JetBrains IDE Support 2.0.8 extension for google chrome and set the port to 9005 as-well."* You do not need that at all -- revert any changes made in this regard back.

Comment: 1) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm 2) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Installing+and+Configuring+XAMPP+with+PhpStorm+IDE

Comment: @LazyOne - wow thanks for these links. I was on the right track but never added the `Server Path Mappings `. After setting it for my project, it worked. Thanks for the guidance.